# Identity between two possible outputs in an integral process

Tags: integration

I have this:

$$\int{\frac{45}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}dx$$

This can be solved in at least 2 different ways:

1)  With trigonometric functions:

$$45sin^{-1}x+C$$

or,

2)  By logarithms

$$45log\sqrt{x^2-1}+x+C$$

If I am right and by:

law:
if *a=b* and *b=c* then *a=c*

**Question**

**If this means that:**

$$45log\sqrt{x^2-1}+x+C=45sin^{-1}x+C$$

**Is this an equality? What is the right relation of the two terms?  What does this means?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting $x=\sec t,dx=\sec t\tan t dt$

$$\int{\frac{45}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}dx=\int\frac{45}{\tan t}\sec t\tan tdt$$
$$=45\int \sec t dt=45\int \frac{\sec t(\sec t+\tan t)}{(\sec t+\tan t)}dt$$

$$=45\ln|\sec t+\tan t|+K (\text{ putting }\sec t+\tan t=u)$$

$$=45\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-1}|+K$$ where $K$ is an arbitrary constant

How does $\sin^{-1}x$ come into picture?

In fact,   if $x=\sin y, y=\sin^{-1}x$

$\displaystyle dx=\cos y dy\implies  \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1{\cos y}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$$\implies \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sin^{-1}x+C$$

Comment: Yeah, I have that formula... $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sin^{-1}x+C$$ so is it right or not? $$\implies \int\frac{45}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=45\sin^{-1}x+C$$

Comment: @HaizumSkallah you asking in the question for the integral of $(\sqrt{x^2-1})^{-1},$ which is not the same as $(\sqrt{1-x^2})^{-1} $

Comment: Now I see... thank you... math-lexia man!!! but does not be mine.. My teacher materials shows in the wrong way...

Answer (score 4):

You have a confusion: the $\arcsin$ function is defined on the interval $[-1,1]$ and
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\arcsin x+C$$
and we have for $x>1$
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\mathrm{arccosh} \ x+C=\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)+C$$

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear enough... can you please explain a little more?

Comment: @HaizumSkallah The functions $x\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and $x\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ are different and have different domains and different anti-derivatives.